# Changing values based on other factors using R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, var

So I have a key factor `lk` that generate random number between 1 and 9. Based on that factor some change must occur in my data as follows;

My data looks like this:

| statue | cost | income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | 43 | 21 |
| n | 5 | 17 |
| n | 27 | 21 |
| n | 26 | 35 |
| t | 39 | 38 |
| n | 12 | 22 |
| t | 42 | 13 |
| t | 38 | 32 |
| n | 39 | 15 |
| t | 25 | 38 |

If `lk > sum (statue=="t")` say `lk == 7 and sum (statue=="t") == 5` so two individuals with the smallest  `cost`  must change their status from  `n`  to  `t`  in this example individual 2 and 6.

And if `lk <= sum (statue=="t")` say `lk == 3 and sum (statue=="t") == 5` so two individuals with the biggest  `salary`  must change their status from  `t`  to  `n`  in this example individual 1 and 7.

I hope I made it clear;

Any ideas please;

Best regards

Comment: How do you break ties?  And are you updating a dataframe with R or a database with a e.g. SQL (flavour)?

Comment: I also don't understand your last condition meaning indiv 1 and 7 would change as they don't have the largest income (which I assume is what you mean by salary) where statue (status?) is already "t".